# what kind of developers use SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql-server

I was reading the differences between SQL Server and SQL Server Compact on the below URL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(v=sql.110).aspx

and I was wondering how can some developer use SQL Serve Compact if it does not support ORDER BY . What type of developers use this SQL Server edition?

Comment: I think one of it's primary uses is testing.  Also are you sure ``order by <column name>`` doesn't work?  I think it's only the ``order by <number>``.  Need confirmation on that though

Comment: It's not a question of "what kind of people would use this" but rather a question of "what kind of projects would benefit from this."  Tools should be decided upon by the features they provide, not by the developers who like them.

Comment: It **does** support `ORDER BY`! The subtlety here is that it supports ordering by column *name* but not by *index*. E.g. `SELECT surname FROM students ORDER BY surname` would work, but `SELECT surname FROM students ORDER BY 1` would not. CE also cannot order by large object fields (text, image, etc). Manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174149(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @gvee, good answer but the table provided by Microsoft in the above given link says that ORDER BY is not supported in SQL Compact. May be they need to update the page.

Comment: @user1451111 the table states `ORDER BY <column number>`. This is not the same as `ORDER BY <column name>`. I have provided a more thorough answer to your question outside of the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What kind of developers use SQL Server Compact Edition

This question is too broad to answer and not appropriate for SO.

> how can some developer use SQL Serve Compact if it does not support ORDER BY

This is not true. I think you've misunderstood the statement in the article you've quoted.

It **does** support `ORDER BY`! The subtlety here is that it supports ordering by column *name* but not by *index*.

```
SELECT surname
FROM   students
ORDER
    BY surname
```

This would work.

```
SELECT surname
FROM   students
ORDER
    BY 1
```

This would not.

*Note: CE also cannot order by large object fields (text, image, etc).*

Have a read of the SELECT statement syntax for CE here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174149(v=sql.110).aspx

```
SELECT select_list 
[ FROM table_source ]
[ WHERE search_condition ] 
[ GROUP BY group_by_expression ] 
[ HAVING search_condition ] 
[ ORDER BY order_expression [ ASC | DESC ] ]
```

See? `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Compact is a good choice for use in development, testing, and low-traffic production scenarios.It can be used with medium-trust applications running in a Web hosting environment

ORDER BY Clause (SQL Server Compact) specifies the sort order for the result set. The ORDER BY clause is not valid in subqueries. You also have an option to fetch only a window or page of results from the resultset using OFFSET-FETCH clause.
Syntax:

[ORDER BY { order_by_expression [ ASC | DESC ] } [ ,...n][] ]
 ::= {OFFSET { integer_constant | offset_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS }    [FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } {integer_constant | fetch_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS } ONLY    ]}

For Example:

SELECT * from E1 UNION SELECT * from E2 ORDER BY col1;

Comment: But the table provided by Microsoft in the above given link says that ORDER BY is not supported in SQL Compact.

Comment: @user1451111 No it only says that the `ORDER BY <column_number>` is not supported, but there is the `ORDER BY <column_name>` form and the last one is supported. See @gvee's answer.